Crontab doesn't apply the changes after editing it with crontab -e
In summary: I ran crontab -e, added a line, saved, said: crontab: installing new crontab, but running crontab -e just shows an old version of the file.
Full explaination:
Yesterday I added a line to cron using crontab -e.
Today when I ran that same command, the line was gone. I confirmed that the cronjob did actually worked, so I didn't understand why it was gone.
So I added the line again, but with some change to the line. Saved the file to the tmp file, and it said "installing new crontab".
Now when I run crontab -l it only shows what I added yesterday.
If I run crontab -e now, it shows the correct line. I tried writing it again, but still, crontab -l only displays the old file.

Like usual, I figure it out right after posting:
Yesterday I ran crontab -e as my user.
Today I ran the crontab -e with sudo command first.
So when I viewed crontab -l without the sudo command, it showed the file from yesterday created by my user.
